# How to use Jasmine unit tests and still get past Lightning CLI?

Tags: unit-test, lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

Like the question says, I'm trying to work out some best practices and frameworks stuff with my team.

One of the things we want to do is unit test our lightning components.  I really like Bob Buzzard's approach, [Unit Testing Lightning Components With jasmine](http://www.slideshare.net/keirb/unit-testing-lightning-components-with-jasmine).   But we also want to be able to use Lightning CLI since we are developing with Locker Service and possible app exchange usage in mind.

When I run lightning CLI on .js files (eg. componentHelper.js), I run into issues if I also include the Jasmine tests in there.   The specs cause CLI to complain about errors like unexpected 'it's and undefined 'spyOn', to name a few.

A couple ideas that have come to mind:

1. Create some kind of task to strip out the unit test code at some point in the development lifecycle.  Maybe gulp or ant can do the work for me.  Obviously need to keep it in place elsewhere.
2. Since CLI is called out specifically by SF, use that and jettison the unit tests.   This idea isn't great.  I'm concerned that it introduces risk.
3. Identify some other means of running unit tests locally using files that never go to the server.  I'm not sure what this would look like. I know that Aura has its own test framework that puts tests in a separate .js file.  I've never used it, though. I'm not sure what potential risks there might be to going down that road.

I'm sure at this point, someone else has dealt with this.  How are people unit testing their lightning components?